# How to enable Submit Button after filling out the required fields?

Tags: nodes

I have created custom Content Type and I would like to disable the submit button, till the user has filled out all the required fields.

I should enable the submit button, once the user fills out the required fields, how do i achieve this?

Comment: In which ever way you do, enable the submit button by default and disable it using Jquery on page load. At least it'll work without Jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

check out `#states visible` `#states invisible` in drupal.

http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for javascript.

This thread should get you started:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?147187-how-to-Disable-enable-submit-button-using-javascript.

I'd create a set of javascript validation functions that once they all returned true for the fields you need it would reenable the submit button.

Here is a link to another, simple, example that may be just what you are looking for:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4083623.htm